# How to connect an existing, non-project, folder to subversion?

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe6

How can i connect a folder in Delphi **Library** path to a folder in Subversion?

### Background

In another Delphi source-control IDE plugin, you can configure what they call *"Global Mappings"*. This means that an arbitrary folder on your hard-drive can be mapped to a folder in source control:

[image]

This means that any amount of arbitrary folder in my **Library** path, i can automatically get the benefits of source control:

- get latest
- merge changes
- history

right from the IDE. The folders just contain arbitrary amounts of source-code files.

### That's fine for Delphi 5

That works fine for Delphi 5, but what about Delphi XE6, and their built-in subversion client?

How do i specify a arbitrary mapping between a folder on my hard-drive, and a corresponding repository and folder on the network/internet/cloud?

## Update: 3/6/2015

Epocalipse just released their updated [VssConneXion for XE6!](http://www.epocalipse.com/downloads.htm) (and XE7, and their SourceConneXion for the same). Finally, i get to use source control in Delphi again!

It really would be super if Bo...Imp...Co...Embarcadero included some documentation on how to use SVN from Delphi. In the meantime, this question goes unsolvable.

Comment: I don't think you want to replicate the solution used by VSS. You want to find the right svn solution to the problem. Whatever the problem is. svn:externals might be the solution. Hard to be sure.

Comment: What about this link, [Subversion Integration in the IDE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Subversion_Integration_in_the_IDE) and this [How To Use Subversion in the IDE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/How_To_Use_Subversion_in_the_IDE).

Answer (score 1):

From the image you've provide that other version control is *SourceSafe* and that probably means Delphi is talking to *SourceSafe* using the *MSSCCI* interface.

That would suggest that since Delphi supports MSSCCI, it should also work with any Subversion plug-in that implements the *MSSCCI* interface.

So one option would be to use Google and search for such a plug-in, of which there are a few to choose from.

I know of at least one such plug-in which is *Agent SVN* since I'm the author of that plug-in. But unfortunately I can't tell you if it works with Delphi as I've never tested it with that IDE.

But as the plug-in works with several other *MSSCCI* IDEs I suspect there is a good chance that it will.

Comment: Ian wants to use the XE6 built in svn integration. But more to the point he wants to know how to set up his projects in svn.

Comment: I do realise that point. My only point is given the built-in Subversion doesn't seem to be working, based on the screen shot posted, there should at least be a second option to getting Delphi working with Subversion. So while that won't be built in Subversion integration, it should still be first class Subversion integration which is probably better than nothing.

Comment: I came back looking to see if anyone figured out how to use SVN from Delphi yet. By the lack of answers i see nobody has. Fortunately, the guys who wrote a decent Source control for Delphi just updated theirs for XE6 and 7!